# Combine several dsnoop devices using the multi plugin

Tags: alsa

In an embedded environment, I have two hw sound input devices. **I want to combine them into a single ALSA interface.** Moreover, **I want to be able to access that interface from multiple applications simultaneously.** Here's what I have so far:

---

```
pcm.multi {
    type multi
    slaves {
        a {
            pcm "hw:0,0"
            channels 2
        }
        b {
            pcm "hw:0,1"
            channels 2
        }
    }
    bindings.0.slave a
    bindings.0.channel 0
    bindings.1.slave a
    bindings.1.channel 1
    bindings.2.slave b
    bindings.2.channel 0
    bindings.3.slave b
    bindings.3.channel 1
}
```

This works for combining the two devices into a single interface, but **this interface can only be used by a single application at once.**

---

```
pcm.snoop_a {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1024
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        channels 2
    }
}
pcm.snoop_b {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 2048
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,1"
        channels 2
    }
}
```

This allows multiple applications to access each interface simultaneously, but **it doesn't combine the two HW sources into a single interface.**

---

Trying to combine the two half solutions, I wrote:

```
pcm.multi_snoop {
    type multi
    slaves {
        a {
            pcm "snoop_a"
            channels 2
        }
        b {
            pcm "snoop_b"
            channels 2
        }
    }
    bindings.0.slave a
    bindings.0.channel 0
    bindings.1.slave a
    bindings.1.channel 1
    bindings.2.slave b
    bindings.2.channel 0
    bindings.3.slave b
    bindings.3.channel 1
}
```

**This does not work:** trying to access the `multi_snoop` interface fails:

```
# arecord -D plug:multi_snoop /dev/null
Recording WAVE '/dev/null' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
ALSA lib pcm_params.c:2162:(snd1_pcm_hw_refine_slave) Slave PCM not usable
arecord: set_params:1310: Broken configuration for this PCM: no configurations available
```

---

Note however that each `dsnoop` device individually can be used inside a `multi` device. This works:

```
pcm.multi_snoop {
    type multi
    slaves {
        a {
            pcm "snoop_a"
            channels 2
        }
    }
    bindings.0.slave a
    bindings.0.channel 0
    bindings.1.slave a
    bindings.1.channel 1
}
```

and the same with `snoop_b`.

It's only when I try to put both `dsnoop` devices inside the same `multi` definition that it fails.

---

**Version information:**

```
# ls /usr/lib/libasound.so*
/usr/lib/libasound.so        /usr/lib/libasound.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/libasound.so.2
# cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.9.113.
```